# Php, check if object with property = value exists in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I think I could do this with a foreach loop like this:

```
 foreach ($haystack as $item)
       if (isset($item->$needle_field) && $item->$needle_field == $needle)
            return true;
 }
```

but i was wandering if it could be done without a loop?

something like:

```
  if(in_array($item->$needle_field == $needle,$haystack)
            return true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but it's not any better:

```
<?php
function make_subject($count, $success) {
    $ret = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->foo = $success ? $i : null;
        $ret[] = $object;
    }
    return $ret;
}

// Change true to false for failed test.
$subject = make_subject(10, true);

if (sizeof(array_filter($subject, function($value) {
    return $value->foo === 3;
}))) {
    echo 'Value 3 was found!';
} else {
    echo 'Value 3 was not found.';
}
```

Outputs `Value 3 was found!`.

I advise you remain with the for loop: it's legible, unlike any tricks to save a line that you might find.

Comment: This will be less efficient than the OP's code because `array_filter()` will be traversing the full array (even if it already finds a qualifying value).  `array_filter()` includes a `return` but this just passes one or more boolean evaluations back in the response -- it doesn't actually halt the iteration of the input array.  Furthermore, the `sizeof()` call can be safely omitted from the condition.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, in modern PHP you can determine if a specific object property contains a specific value without a classic loop by combining the forces of `array_column()` (which has evolved to also handle arrays of objects) and `in_array()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/D5v2L))

```
$objects = [
    (object)['cats' => 2],
    (object)['dogs' => 2],
    (object)['fish' => 10],
    (object)['birds' => 1],
];

$needleField = 'cats';
$needleValue = 2;

var_export(
    in_array($needleValue, array_column($objects, $needleField))
);
// output: true
```

The advantage of this technique is the obviously concise syntax.  This is a perfectly acceptable approach for relatively small volumes of data.

A possible disadvantage to this technique is that `array_column()` will be generating a new array of all of values that relate to the `$needleField`.

In my above demo, `array_column()` will only generate a single-element array because there is only one `cats` property in all of the objects.  If we were processing a relatively large volume of data, then it would be inefficient to bother collecting all of the qualifying `cats` values and then run `in_array()` when only one match is necessary to return `true`.

For "large" volumes of data where performance is a primary criterion for script design, a classic `foreach` loop would be a better choice and as soon as an object satisfies the rules, then the loop should be halted via `return` or `break`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jlu7s))

```
function hasPropertyValue(array $objects, $property, $value): bool {
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        if (property_exists($object, $property) && $object->{$property} === $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var_export(
    hasPropertyValue($objects, $needleField, $needleValue)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if the array you are searching is out of your control. **But**, if you are the one building the array of objects to be searched, you can structure it using the needle as array keys to be used with [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) when you are searching.

For example, instead of making your `$haystack` array like this:

```
[
  {
    'needle_field' => $needle
  },
  ...
]
```

Make it like this:

```
[
  $needle => {
    'needle_field' => $needle
  },
  ...
]
```

And search like this:

```
if (array_key_exists($needle, $haystack)) {
  return true;
}
```

Finally, if you need to, you can convert back to an integer indexed array by using [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$haystack = array_values($haystack);
```

This may not work in all situations but it worked great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with `array_key_exists`:

```
if (array_key_exists($needle_field, $haystack) { 
  if ($haystack[$needle_field] == $needle) {
    echo "$needle exists";
  }
}
```